# Crashlytics crashed

Tags: android, crash, crashlytics

My project use crashlytics, but it's always crash and not sent report:

```
1673-3919/io.docchat.android.debug E/Crashlytics﹕ Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.Z@428b99d0
com.crashlytics.android.internal.aD: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/io.docchat.android.debug/files/.TwitterSdk/v/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/54F832010096-022D-0689-446ED43C9162.cls: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.a(SourceFile:2655)
        at com.crashlytics.android.W.a(SourceFile:55)
        at com.crashlytics.android.aa.a(SourceFile:81)
        at com.crashlytics.android.D.a(SourceFile:1014)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/io.docchat.android.debug/files/.TwitterSdk/v/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/54F832010096-022D-0689-446ED43C9162.cls: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.a(SourceFile:2652)
        at com.crashlytics.android.W.a(SourceFile:55)
        at com.crashlytics.android.aa.a(SourceFile:81)
        at com.crashlytics.android.D.a(SourceFile:1014)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.a(SourceFile:2652)
        at com.crashlytics.android.W.a(SourceFile:55)
        at com.crashlytics.android.aa.a(SourceFile:81)
        at com.crashlytics.android.D.a(SourceFile:1014)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
1673-3915/io.docchat.android.debug I/Crashlytics﹕ Crashlytics report upload complete: 54F8320003D0-022C-0689-446ED43C9162.cls
1673-3923/io.docchat.android.debug W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=28: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41839898)
1673-3918/io.docchat.android.debug I/Crashlytics﹕ Crashlytics report upload complete: 54F8320100DE-022E-0689-446ED43C9162.cls
```

Why it's happend? I've not use twitter at all. And Twitter app isn't installed on device.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. This was fixed in version 2.2.3 of the Crashlytics SDK. If you update to that version, you'll be all set!  [Release notes here.](https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/overview/changelog)

Comment: I am seeing this issue with version `2.7.1`. Is it a critical error or it can be ignored?

Comment: If you see an error with uploading crash reports, then it means that the crash report couldn't be sent so most apps would find this to be an important error. However, I haven't seen other reports of this issue since the fix two years ago. Do you see this on every crash?

Comment: I am seeing it during bootup of the device where I start a service on bootup that runs in its own process and it might be trying to upload a pending crash report from previous run? I am seeing it in my dev environment, but haven't verified it in prod. It is not easily reproducible seems like. Would let you know if I see it again.

Comment: Now I am seeing this issue with version 2.9.0.How can I resolve it?

Comment: I'd love to see a new log or output to confirm including the SDK version in the logs. I haven't heard from other folks that this has started happening again.

Comment: Hi @Mike Bonnell, I am facing this same issue, this is the Crashlytics SDK version `2.9.1@aar` and `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'` The error that I get is this - `Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionReport io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname reports.crashlytics.com not verified:`

Comment: It will be tough to diagnose this with only that information. Can you send a full debug log to support(at)fabric(dot)io and reference this thread? It's also helpful to know on which devices and OS versions you're seeing this on and if the devices are rooted.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks!